# Springboard failed to launch application with error 3, 0, 4, etc

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Why Xcode fails to launch application in simulator?

I've gone through many solutions on the web but sometimes they work and sometimes they don't.

Many times what I did to solve the problem is quitting the simulator, deleting the application,

resetting content settings of simulator, and clean and build.

But why should I try anyone (all) of these each time.

Xcode is eating the development time in by having all these bugs.

And even sometimes it gives lost connection, app quit unexpectedly errors.

What are Apple guys are doing? They just released Xcode with all these bugs in it.

Xcode 4.5 or 4.6 do not have these issues for me.

Finally I request all of you to give any good solution that saves time in solving these bloody issues.

Answer (score 83):

By **Quiting simulator** and again **running the project** in Xcode solve this issue.. This error arises while changing simulator versions from 64bit to 32bit.

Comment: I was running on simulator and had to delete the residual apps sitting on the simulator.  I suspect some sort of naming conflict contributed to this error.

Answer (score 8):

I used `iOS Simulator`>`Reset Content and Settings..`.It will reset all the applications in our simulator and then run your application in XCode.
For me It worked..

Answer (score 0):

Quit your xcode,change your project address then run again. 
It works for me.