# iPhone Simulator Error: SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: -3 or 4 etc

Tags: ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5

I face this problem each time i stop and run the app again. I googled and found a lot of answers, e.g. this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970678/springboard-failed-to-launch-application-with-error-3-0-4-etc) but only fix the problem temporarily, I wish there was a way to fix it permanently.

[image]

Thanx in advance.

Solution: I think the problem was related to Xcode version specific as now I am using Xcode 6 and now the issue no longer exist.

Answer (score 2):

select your simulator

choose:iosimulator->Reset Content and Settings.
or else
ctrl+shift+H , double tap the H and close all the application that runs.
ctrl is an windows key in mac

Comment: Thanx @sadeesh but it is also not a permanent solution. It seems a bug in Xcode5, is it?

Comment: Maybe you just upgrade your XCode as 5.0.2.

Comment: ok,its note not the ctrl+shift+k instead use ctrl+shift+H button double tap the H...

Answer (score 1):

same problem for me too.

by Quitting simulator and again running the project in Xcode solved this issue for me..

Answer (score 0):

I know there are already some answers. But, for me, I just made sure to resolve the warnings. I had not set the identifier for a segue. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue after I installed the newest macOS version and the iOS simulator on Xcode fired me.

I have tried the solutions above for myself and the solutions are given on this page: [Xcode 6.4/7 crashing after El Capitan beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803585/xcode-6-4-7-crashing-after-el-capitan-beta) .But they did not work for me.

My final solution was to uninstall the current one and installed new Xcode version. It worked for me.